# How to do classification based on different types of input

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I want to know if there is any way to do a classification based on different input types.

Basically, I have the image dog vs cat dataset from Kaggle and also the sound dog vs cat dataset and I want to show that by combining models from audio alone and image alone we could get a better accuracy.

I read things on ensemble learning where we can combine different models with average precision to get a higher accuracy but these are doing the classification on same types of inputs whereas here I want to do classification by using image and audio as inputs. I also read things from Keras using mixed input but this work only for combining tabular data with images but not sound with images...

I did not find any labelled dataset of dog vs cat videos from which I could extract frames and audio and then apply a CNN on both to do the classification.
Do you have any idea on how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Hi! I think combining results of  two different models for sound classification and image recognition will give better result for in case you could not video feed input for classifying dog and cat  . Attached links for [sound classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/audio_classification/overview) and [image recognition](https://data-flair.training/blogs/cats-dogs-classification-deep-learning-project-beginners/)

Comment: If you want to create your own data set , you can scrap through Youtube through youtube scraper program, But using a single model for recognising audio and video feed won't give accurate results.